# Empty Repeatable Fields in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5 app, I have a set of repeatable field groups, each with a `name` field and a `price` field.

Here's the HTML on page load:

```
<div id="js-new-line-items" style="display: none">
    <div class="repeatable-fields">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn__add-field u-text-right" href="#" id="js-show-line-item-form">
    Or add a new line item
</a>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
// Add new line items
var x = 0;
$( "#js-show-line-item-form" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#js-new-line-items').show();
    x++; //text box increment
    $(".repeatable-fields").append('<div class="field__repeatable"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-name" placeholder="Enter New Line Item Name" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][name]" data-name-id="'+x+'" type="text"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-price" placeholder="Enter Price" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][price]" data-price-id="'+x+'" type="text"></div>');
        // Display Line item preview in bill
      $('#js-display-custom-lineItem').append('<div class="bill-section__body-row"><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-name-'+x+'"></span><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-price-'+x+'"></span></div>');
});
```

And for legibility, here's the unpacked HTML that function appends:

```
<div class="field__repeatable">
    <input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-name" placeholder="Enter New Line Item Name" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][name]" data-name-id="'+x+'" type="text">
    <input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-price" placeholder="Enter Price" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][price]" data-price-id="'+x+'" type="text">
</div>
```

Now, this all works well. I can add as many field groups as I need, and the input names increment correctly.

However, when I submit the form, this is my request object:

```
array:8 [▼
    "_token" => "dKnCstu3pbQoXnH3bM5QTVDrHAZfwiKc7gPdAcDM"
    "description" => "test"
    "new_lineItem" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => ""
            "price" => ""
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => ""
            "price" => ""
        ]
    ]
]
```

My `name` and `price` values are empty. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why this is happening. Can anyone spot any errors with this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I test your code (just copy and pasted in my laravel project) and it was working fine. i.e. fields were not empty.

Following is the code for your reference (**You can compare where you are missing something** ) :

**HTML Code**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url('form-submit')}}">

{{ csrf_field() }}

<div id="js-new-line-items" style="display: none">
    <div class="repeatable-fields">
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn__add-field u-text-right" href="#" id="js-show-line-item-form">
    Or add a new line item
</a>

<input type="submit" name="">
```

**Javascript Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    // Add new line items
    var x = 0;
    $( "#js-show-line-item-form" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#js-new-line-items').show();
        x++; //text box increment
        $(".repeatable-fields").append('<div class="field__repeatable"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-name" placeholder="Enter New Line Item Name" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][name]" data-name-id="'+x+'" type="text"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-price" placeholder="Enter Price" name="new_lineItem['+x+'][price]" data-price-id="'+x+'" type="text"></div>');
            // Display Line item preview in bill
          $('#js-display-custom-lineItem').append('<div class="bill-section__body-row"><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-name-'+x+'"></span><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-price-'+x+'"></span></div>');
    });

});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('form-submit', 'testController@formsubmit');
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class testController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function formsubmit(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

**Result**

### [image: Form]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Javascript :

```
// Add new line items
var x = 0;
$( "#js-show-line-item-form" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#js-new-line-items').show();
    x++; //text box increment
    $(".repeatable-fields").append('<div class="field__repeatable"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-name" placeholder="Enter New Line Item Name" name="new_lineItem[name][]" data-name-id="'+x+'" type="text"><input class="js-new-line-item-field js-new-line-item-price" placeholder="Enter Price" name="new_lineItem[price][]" data-price-id="'+x+'" type="text"></div>');
        // Display Line item preview in bill
      $('#js-display-custom-lineItem').append('<div class="bill-section__body-row"><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-name-'+x+'"></span><span class="bill-section__body-row-item" id="js-new-display-line-item-price-'+x+'"></span></div>');
});
```